# Reading string user input into an array of any size

Tags: c++

so I'm currently trying to read user input into a char array, but every single example I've looked at defines the size of the array upon its initialization. What I'm looking for, essentially, is a way to read user input (perhaps with getline, as I would want to read user input as a string) and store it in an array.

Let's say a user inputs this into the program:

```
This is a string
```

I would want the array size to be able to fit that string, and place the null terminator after the "g". Then, another user could put a string of any size that they so desired into the program, but I would basically want my program to always make the array size just enough to contain what was read in from input.

I haven't been able to get this working and it's been a couple of hours of browsing endless pages, so any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You should almost certainly be using a `std::string`, which is internally an automatically resizing array of characters.  To read input:`std::string my_string_variable; if (getline(std::cin, my_string_variable)) ...use it...; else std::cerr << "couldn't read string\n";`.  A language-level array such as `char ca[10];` can not be resized at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tony Delroy said on his comment (I can't comment yet), you should be using  **std::string**.

If you really need an char array, as parameter to a function for example, you can use the function **c_str()** to get the content of the **std::string** as a **const char*** array or if you need a **char*** array, you can copy the content of the array given by **c_str()** to a dynamically allocated array, using

```
char* cstr = new char[str.length() + 1];
strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
```

As an addend, you need to include the header **cstring** in order to use the function strcpy and need to use **delete[] cstr** to delete the **char*** when you're not going to use it anymore

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

// string argument as std::string
void foo(string str) {
    // function body
}

// argument as const char*
void bar(const char* str) {
    // function body
}

// argument as char*
void baz(char* str) {
    // function body
}

int main() {
    string str;

    getline(cin, str);

    foo(str);
    bar(str.c_str());

    char* cstr = new char[str.length() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
    baz(cstr);

    delete[] cstr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is at best poor attempt to answer. Please improve it!

Answer (score 0):

you should use std::string for that.
the null terminator has no use in std::string, because you can just use:

```
string.size()
```

to get the size of the user input.

if want to traverse a string like a char array one by one it should look like something like this:

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);

for (int i = 0; i < input.size() ; i++)
{
   std::cout << input[i];
}
```